# I want to show available time and booked time to the user

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am working on booking scheme in which i want to show user whether time slots on selected date is available or booked.

```
 <td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">
<?php   

        $query5=mysql_query("select * from doctorbooking where aday='".$_REQUEST['date']."'");

        $query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5);

        echo $query6['atime'];
?>
if($query6>0)
{
<?php echo $array_of_time[$key].' - '.$array_of_time[$key+1]; ?><br /><span style="color:red;"><?php echo "Booked"; ?></span> 
}
else
{
<?php echo $array_of_time[$key].' - '.$array_of_time[$key+1]; ?><br /><span style="color:red;"><?php echo "Available"; ?></span>
}


</td>
```

First I have selected data from the database on selected date.It is showing booked and available both.I think i have applied if else condition in wrong way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no loop here.

Comment: I am applying if else condition.But I have applied in wrong way.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$query6` is an array so you'll have to loop to be capable to apply the `if/else` condition. Also, there are syntax errors with php and html tags.

Something like this should work (not tested) :

```
<td style="border:1px solid;padding:11px;">
    <?php
        $query5 = mysql_query("select * from doctorbooking where aday = '" . $_REQUEST['date'] . "'");
        $query6 = mysql_fetch_array($query5);

        var_dump($query6); // Use var_dump() function since $query6 is an array

        foreach ($query6 as $key => $value) { // Use foreach to loop through $query6 array
            if ($value > 0) {
                echo $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1] . '<br /><span style="color:red;">Booked</span>';
            } else {
                echo $array_of_time[$key] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$key+1] . '<br /><span style="color:red;">Available</span>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

Hope it helps.

PS : be carefull, the var `$array_of_time` is not defined in your code.

Comment: Please tell me this in php tag.

Comment: Yes there is bad syntax in your code. Wait a minute, I'll try to fixe that.

Comment: It is showing syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';'.@Adrien Leber

Comment: Is the `var_dump()` works ? If no, you surely got another error somewhere else in your code. Also, what is `$array_of_time` ? It is not defined in your code.

Comment: Aw, sorry, it's a `foreach` loop, not a `for` loop. My fault...
See the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Adrien Leber.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123590/discussion-between-rahul-pamnani-and-adrien-leber).